# How to use a Nodejs module with AMD require

Tags: node.js, requirejs, electron, monaco-editor

I use monaco-editor in an electron app,and I want to add my own grammar support;

I tried to build a plugin like monaco-editor's grammar support library such as monaco-html or monaco-css, Monaco-editor use WebWorker to load those grammar lib,and here's the problem:

in the WebWorker,I can only access a build-in AMD require, I can't get any Node.js module with AMD require,any way I can get the nodeRequire function or require a Nodejs Module with AMD require?

any advise can be helpful,Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a test, I tried adding a pointer to the `CommonJS` `require` function to the `requirejs` function in my `index.js` file. Something like this: `requirejs._require = require;`. Then you should be able to use `require._require('module')` to get to the node module. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @JacobHeater thanks for your suggestion，but I'm afraid it can't work, monaco-editor start a web worker (an individual thread) for every language support lib,I can get the require function in Main thread, but seems no way to pass a function to another thread.